# Does there exist an infinite abelian subgroup of the orthogonal group $O(n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The orthogonal group $O(n)$ is the group of all matrices $A$ such that $A^{-1}=A^t$, subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.

If this subgroup does exists, how would I go about finding it?

Comment: Consider rotations about a single axis.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Suppose I consider a rotation through an angle of $\theta$ radians. This generates a cyclic (hence, abelian) subgroup of $O(n)$ - do you see how the order of that group relates to $\theta$? Is there a $\theta$ which yields an infinite group?

Comment: I see how they relate, but I don't understand how there could be a $\theta$ that gives an infinite group. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Chris If you like the matrix approach more than the geometrical, think of the identity matrix in which you change the upper-left $2\times 2$ submatrix to $\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Chris Let's say I tell you that rotation by $\theta$ generates a group of order $k$. What do you know about $\theta$? (For instance, how big a group does "rotate by $30^\circ$" generate?)

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the rotation matrix by an angle $\theta\pi$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ $M(\theta\pi)$, with $\theta$ rational ($\theta=p/q, p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$), then

$M(\theta\pi)^{(1+2q)}= M((1+2q)\theta\pi)=M(\theta\pi)$ and we have a finite group.

When $\theta$ is an irrational number we have an infinite group.